# Extending Error handler using plugin method is not working

Tags: magento2, php, plugin, after-plugin

I need to save errors in my database. So I am trying to extend Error Handler in my custom module using plugin method. But it is not working. Here is my code

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler">
        <plugin name="BridgeErrorNotificationErrorHandler" type="Bridge\ErrorNotification\Plugin\ErrorHandlerPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**ErrorHandlerPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Bridge\ErrorNotification\Plugin;

class ErrorHandlerPlugin
{
    protected $errorPhrases = [
        E_ERROR => 'Error',
        E_WARNING => 'Warning',
        E_PARSE => 'Parse Error',
        E_NOTICE => 'Notice',
        E_CORE_ERROR => 'Core Error',
        E_CORE_WARNING => 'Core Warning',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR => 'Compile Error',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'Compile Warning',
        E_USER_ERROR => 'User Error',
        E_USER_WARNING => 'User Warning',
        E_USER_NOTICE => 'User Notice',
        E_STRICT => 'Strict Notice',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR => 'Recoverable Error',
        E_DEPRECATED => 'Deprecated Functionality',
        E_USER_DEPRECATED => 'User Deprecated Functionality',
    ]; 

    public function afterhandler($errorNo, $errorStr, $errorFile, $errorLine)
    { 
        if (strpos($errorStr, 'DateTimeZone::__construct') !== false) {
        // there's no way to distinguish between caught system exceptions and warnings
          return false;
        }

       $errorNo = $errorNo & error_reporting();
       if ($errorNo == 0) {
         return false;
       }

       $msg = isset($this->errorPhrases[$errorNo]) ? $this->errorPhrases[$errorNo] : "Unknown error ({$errorNo})";
       $msg .= ": {$errorStr} inn {$errorFile} on line {$errorLine}";
       $msg .= "  just for testing";
       throw new \Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

To test this I am just adding `$msg .= "  just for testing";` in message.

Comment: If you use AFTER plugin, you don't have the input parameters **$errorNo, $errorStr, $errorFile, $errorLine**. You just have the output parameter from the handler method which is true or false. If you need to change the behavior of this method, you have to use the AROUND plugin.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: tried, but still no change

Comment: oh, i found out the problem. You cannot create a plugin for classes that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped.
Take a look here for a custom handler: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167463/magento-2-custom-error-and-exception-handling/167474#167474

Comment: can i use preference method?